# Python: BT is not closing socket properly?

Tags: python, bluetooth

I'm working with BT in python and realized it gets faulty after some time, so I wanted to introduce connect/close in the main loop, but looks like not working in my code. So I've thrown around this testing bit of code which unfortunately does the same - not closing socket.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
import bluetooth
import time

class BluetoothHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.addr = "12:13:14:04:26:23"
        self.sock = None
        
    def connect(self):
        try:
            if self.sock is None:
                self.sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
                self.sock.connect((self.addr, 1))
                print(f"Connected to {self.addr}")

        except bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError as e:
            if "Connection refused" in str(e):
                print("Connection Refused. Check if the device is discoverable and connectable.")
            else:
                print(f"Error: {e}")

    def close(self):
        try:
            if self.sock is not None:
                self.sock.close()
                print("Connection closed.")
            else:
                print("No socket to close.")

        except bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError as e:
            print(f"Error during close: {e}")
    


handler = BluetoothHandler()

try:
    while True:
        handler.connect()
        time.sleep(5)
        handler.close()
        time.sleep(5)
        handler.close()
        time.sleep(5)
    
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

finally:
    print("over")
```

ouput of this bit of code is:

```
dietpi@rpi:/opt/dev/project$ sudo python3 test.py 
Connected to 12:13:14:04:26:23
Connection closed.
Connection closed.
Connection closed.
Connection closed.
Connection closed.
```

I'm expecting something more like this:

```
dietpi@rpi:/opt/dev/project$ sudo python3 test.py 
Connected to 12:13:14:04:26:23
Connection closed.
No socket to close.
No socket to close.
```

Comment: You don't reset `self.sock = None` in `.close()`, so all subsequent `.connect` calls hit non-None `self.sock` and silently pass.

Comment: @STerliakov thank you. I though that socket.close does it automatically. Good to know. Thank you!